# Is ARM PL310 only in Cortex A9 processor?

Tags: arm, cpu-cache

I know that ARM Cortex A9 processor can be equipped with PL310 cache controller.

However, I'm not sure if other ARM processors may support PL310 cache controller?
I searched Cortex A7, A53, and A57, none of them seems supporting PL310.
Is it possible that ARM abandoned the PL310 cache controller?

Comment: The list of supported ARM processors for this cache controller can be found [here](http://www.arm.com/products/system-ip/controllers/peripherals/index.php)

Comment: Thanks, I found "All AXI processors, in particular Cortex-A9, Cortex-A5, Cortex-R4, Cortex-R5, Cortex-R7, ARM11MPCore, ARM1176, ARM1156, Mali-200" in the link. It seems that Cortex A9 is the latest processor that supports the PL310 controller. Maybe ARM is deprecating the controller? in other words, they won't want to add the controller in the processor in the future?

Comment: Contact ARM if you want to know the answer to that question.  Of course logic dictates is that if they do deprecate the controller something will replace it.  Since any hardware changes will require engineering work on your part anyways you shouldn't worry about what might happen just design with what you have now.